# goofys: Can't access subdir from top dir even as a root user

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, rsync, mount, goofys

I mounted the bucket from S3 with the following command

`sudo goofys -o allow_other mybucket /mnt/buckets/mybucket/`

inside mybucket, there are a bunch of subdirectories.

When I do rsync or cp (with sudo) some subdirectories, I ran into a problem:

```
sudo cp -rv /mnt/buckets/mybucket/a /destination
cp: cannot access '/mnt/buckets/mybucket/a/b/c': Input/output error

sudo rsync -arv --delete /mnt/buckets/mybucket/a /destination
rsync: [sender] readdir("/mnt/buckets/mybucket/a/b/c"): Input/output error (5)
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
```

however, if I copy or rsync full path sudo `cp -rv /mnt/buckets/mybucket/a/b/c /destination` there was no problem at all.

I did `ls -al`, all directories and subdirectories have all permissions for root and other user

when I did `ls -al /mnt/buckets/mybucket/a/b/c` first time, I got this error:

```
ls: reading directory '/mnt/buckets/mybucket/a/b/c': Input/output error
```

but after I kept running the same command, I finally saw all the directories and files under it.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?